# is there a way to activate the file when saving it in HANA studio?

Tags: hana-studio

When working in HANA studio I have to right click and activate my files after I save them in order for them to take effect. Is there a way to set it up so the file is activated when I save?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the value under the preferences. It's a check box to auto activate upon save. It's in the preference section for the HANA plugin.